# How to access to a nested object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to access a nested Json file, didn't figure out how to do it:

```
  var createPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ddpclient.call('create_emailConnection',[ddpclient.collections.email], function (err, result) {
          console.log([ddpclient.collections.email])
          resolve();
          if (err) {
            logger.error(0, '❌ error user_created')
          } else {
            logger.debug(5, 'users marked as created')
          }
        })
      })
```

This return

email.json

```
{ HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S: 
     { _id: 'HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S',
       batch: '2017-user-created-by-websocket',
       creationIP: 'None',
       creationDate: 2018-06-14T13:23:58.786Z,
       state: [Object],
    },
    M101KSi360g7cER8D5: 
     { _id: 'M101KSi360g7cER8D5',
       batch: '2017-box-created-by-websocket',
       creationIP: 'None',
       creationDate: 2018-06-14T13:24:31.145Z,
       state: [Object],
      } }
```

So I want to get the _id on my json file

Comment: Side note: Don't resolve the promise on error, that hides the fact an error occurred. Reject on error, that's what promise rejection is for.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the object keys `HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S`, `M101KSi360g7cER8D5` looks random and unpredictable so you can use `Object.keys()` on the array object and loop through them to get the value of `_id`.

```js
var arr = [ { HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S: 
     { _id: 'HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S',
       batch: '2017-user-created-by-websocket',
       creationIP: 'None',
       creationDate: '2018-06-14T13:23:58.786Z'
    },
    M101KSi360g7cER8D5: 
     { _id: 'M101KSi360g7cER8D5',
       batch: '2017-box-created-by-websocket',
       creationIP: 'None',
       creationDate: '2018-06-14T13:24:31.145Z'
      } } ];
      
arr.forEach((obj)=>{
  keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach((key)=>{
   console.log(obj[key]._id);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/reduce) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/object/keys)

You have an `array` of `objects` with each `object` having multiple `objects` with each being mapped to `_id` being `key` of object. Now, you can reduce the array to concatenate all the `_ids`. As the `key` of object and `_id` are same, you can use the key of object to extract the `_id`.

```js
var arr = [{ HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S: { _id: 'HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S',batch: '2017-user-created-by-websocket',creationIP: 'None',creationDate: '2018-06-14T13:23:58.786Z'},M101KSi360g7cER8D5:{ _id: 'M101KSi360g7cER8D5',batch: '2017-box-created-by-websocket',creationIP: 'None',creationDate: '2018-06-14T13:24:31.145Z'} } ];
let ids = arr.reduce((a,c) => [...a, ...Object.keys(c)], []);
console.log(ids);
```

**EDIT**

```js
let obj = { HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S: { _id: 'HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S',batch: '2017-user-created-by-websocket',creationIP: 'None',creationDate: '2018-06-14T13:23:58.786Z'},M101KSi360g7cER8D5:{ _id: 'M101KSi360g7cER8D5',batch: '2017-box-created-by-websocket',creationIP: 'None',creationDate: '2018-06-14T13:24:31.145Z'} };
let ids = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: I did       let ids = ddpclient.collections.email.reduce((a,c) => [...a, ...Object.keys(c)], []);
      console.log(ids)
it tell me reduce is not a function

Comment: @EyTa - Is the above email.json stored in `ddpclient.collections.email` ?

Comment: It's a call to the database my json is like this sorry not an array i'll modify my question one second

Comment: var arr = { HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S: { _id: 'HEDGz2aafs2UdSvT3S',batch: '2017-user-created-by-websocket',creationIP: 'None',creationDate: '2018-06-14T13:23:58.786Z'},M101KSi360g7cER8D5:{ _id: 'M101KSi360g7cER8D5',batch: '2017-box-created-by-websocket',creationIP: 'None',creationDate: '2018-06-14T13:24:31.145Z'} }

Comment: @EyTa - See my updated answer. You just need `Object.keys`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.map(x => Object.keys(x).map(y => x[y]._id))
```

Which will return you an array of the properties `_id`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ujhfwz0g/3/